# React: Is it safe to alter attributes of the element returned by a callback ref?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a scenario where I pass a function a child component, and the child invokes it in a ref callback to send the ref back to the parent. I am currently doing this, because parent knows it wants to wrap some child (but the child can be *any* React component), and the child doesn't know it's wrapped by the parent. The parent is used to add extra stylings and event listeners on the root element of its child component.

My question is, it safe to modify the attributes or event listeners of the child root element returned by the ref? I thought the any modifications may get lost if the child component updates and re-renders, but so far, it seems to work fine. React documentation doesn't mention any limitations for an element from a ref, either. But, is this really safe?

Comment: *it seems to work fine* - what does work fine? This is very specific to your case, and the question doesn't show it. In general it's not a good thing because messing with the framework may have unexpected results, and a degree of unexpectedness depends on your own expectations. DOM elements are reused by the framework. If an element is not removed, changes may persist even if a component is reinstantiated. Should this be considered 'safe' or 'unsafe'?

Comment: I wanted to specifically know if attaching attributes on elements returned by callback ref is handled consistently by React, or. attributes are promised to persist and event handlers are attached and handled by React. This is obviously not the case I suppose because the callback ref just returns a regular element, so I need to manage attributes and event handlers by myself. Am I correct?

Comment: Can you update the question with https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to reflect your case? The answer may depend on it. Do you mean DOM and not React element by 'regular element'? Usually you should avoid accessing DOM directly where possible.